# Getting text value in closest preceding sibling by class with Mechanize/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

Currently I'm looping over table rows and getting values from a td, putting them in a sorted hash identified by a value in a sibling td:

**Ruby snippet**

```
@counts = Hash.new
agent.page.search('.child').each do |child|
  @counts[child.css('td')[0].text.strip!] = child.css('td')[1].text.gsub(/,/,'').to_i
end

puts @counts.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h
```

**HTML structure**

```
<tr class="parent">
  <td class="info">Type</td>
  <td>12,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="child">
  <td class="info">Sub Type</td>
  <td>9,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="child">
  <td class="info">Sub Type</td>
  <td>3,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent">
  <td class="info">Type</td>
  <td>11,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="child">
  <td class="info">Sub Type</td>
  <td>11,000</td>
</tr>
```

Now I would like to change the hash keys, by concatenating them with the text value in a td belonging to the parent tr. So in the above HTML structure, instead of "Sub Type" => 9000, "Sub Type" => 3000, etc. I would like to get "Type Sub Type" => 9000, "Type Sub Type" => 3000, etc.

How do I get the first preceding sibling with a certain class, when the number of siblings is unknown?

Comment: How can your hash have multiple keys with same text ?

Comment: It doesn't, sorry, my HTML example contains duplicate values for the info td, but the more complex real HTML doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this a different way, loop through all `tr` elements (parent and child), keep the last found parent type and then concatenate the last parent type when you get to a child.

```rb
@counts = Hash.new

parent = nil
agent.page.search('.parent, .child').each do |node|
  type = node.css('td')[0].text.strip
  value = node.css('td')[1].text.gsub(/,/, '').to_i

  if node['class'].include? 'parent'
    parent = type
  else
    @counts["#{parent} #{type}"] = value
  end
end

puts @counts.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h
```

Also, hashes are by nature an unsorted data structure. If you want to retain order, then your best bet would be an array of tuples. In other words, `[['Type Sub Type', 12000], ['Type Sub Type', 11000], ..., ['Type Sub Type', 3000]]`. Just remove the `.t_h` at the end of your last line to get that kind of result.

Comment: I would probably iterate `.parent` first and then `+ .child` but this works too.